# True 3D web font type

Tags: fonts, 3d

I'm developing a 3D website (I mean you navigate the web with 3d glasses) and I'm getting frustrated with the texts.

Text headers should be in 3D too, but I can't find any 3d font type.

One solution could be overload the designer and create this texts as images, but it would be very expensive and bring internationalization problems.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question, but what *is* a 3D font type in this context? What characteristics would it have to have? I don't understand.

Comment: @Pekka - I assume a font where the characters have "real" depth.

Comment: Here is an example of real 3d text. http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:3D_glasses#3D_text_using_CSS. Unfortunately if you inspect the text, you can see it's a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most attractive solution would be using either a server-side scripting language or jQuery to automatically apply the effect shown in the uncyclopedia link to arbitrary content. I gather the essence of it is this:

```
<div style="position:relative;letter-spacing:2px;"> 
<p style="position:absolute;left:-2px;color:#f00;width:100%;">Text</p> 
<p style="position:absolute;left:2px;color:#0ff;width:100%;">Text</p> 
<p style="position:absolute;left:0px;color:#000;width:100%;">Text</p> 
<p style="visibility:hidden;">Text</p> 
</div>
```

If you don't need to support non-Javascript clients, a jQuery solution would be preferable because the text content would remain properly indexable by search engines, and readable by screen readers. Also, you could have a "Turn 3D on / off" switch.

Comment: Good solution, but I'd prefer a css font type. The 3D/2D switch exists already. I was thinking about developing a server-side function that, given a string, returns a processed 3D/2D text depending on the user settings, but the client-side solution seems better. I'll be working on it, thanks.